# Ruby rounding problems 1.005 vs 0.005

Tags: ruby

Why?

```
irb(main):001:0> 1.005.round(2)
=> 1.0
irb(main):002:0> 0.005.round(2)
=> 0.01
irb(main):010:0> puts RUBY_VERSION
2.1.2
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Float.html#method-i-round

Comment: "Float objects represent inexact real numbers using the native architecture's double-precision floating point representation.". There is accuracy problem with Floats. In python : 1.0/10=0.10000000000000001